# How to install IIS on Azure Windows VM using Azure Cli

Tags: windows, azure, devops, azure-cli

After Running this command on Azure Cli:

```
az vm extension set --publisher Microsoft.Compute --version 1.8 --name CustomScriptExtension --vm-name avmUat --resource-group argUat --settings '{"commandToExecute":"powershell.exe Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server"}'
```

I get this error

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
>   8d6972da-6d46-42e8-a053-f8e899348893. VM has reported a failure when
>   processing extension 'CustomScriptExtension'. Error message: "Invalid
>   handler configuration. Exiting. Error Message: Error converting value
>   "{commandToExecute:powershell.exe Install-WindowsFeature -Name
>   Web-Server}" to type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.Plugins.CustomScriptHandler.PublicSettings'.
>   Path 'runtimeSettings[0].handlerSettings.publicSettings', line 5,
>   position 102.".

**Edit:**
The result when I run it in powershell on Azure Cloud Shell:
[image]

**Bash** and this is on bash (Gladly it worked)
[image]

Comment: don't you need to add `-command` before the scriptblock of calling powershell.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that these commands do not work in the Azure CLI locally on the **windows command prompt**. You should run these on a **bash** environment.

With the same Azure CLI version. The same commands could work in [Azure cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) but not local Azure CLI in command prompt. I also tried running it on local Azure CLI `2.0.58`, still failure.

Moreover, Here is the same [Sample script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-cli-sample-create-vm-iis?toc=%2Fcli%2Fazure%2Ftoc.json#sample-script), which is running in a **bash** environment.

Run this on my local command prompt.
[image]

Run it on Azure Cloud Shell
[image]

Comment: This is not the answer but it help me a lot to get back to the right path